# How to use Var Dump to update SQL record using $_POST

Tags: php, mysql

I want to send input data from a form on publish.php to updateCopy.php that will then update the "postCopy" column on my SQL database.

Here's my code so far:

**publish.php**

```
<form action="\.\.\updateCopy.php" method="post" id="newCopy">
<input type="text" name="postCopy">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

**updateCopy.php**

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "main";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "UPDATE posts SET postCopy= var_dump ($_POST["postCopy"]); WHERE id=123456789";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

When I attempt to run this process I get the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)

Is anyone able to tell me how I can effectivley use var_dump ($_POST["postCopy"]); to include the updated postCopy info and then update my SQL db?

Comment: Guess where your query stops?

Comment: PS. Learn to use prepared statements with bind variables, or learn how easy SQL injection is to trash your database

Comment: Honestly, I'm with @MarkBaker here; I don't know why you even would want to do that. So tell us; why?

Comment: what is `var_dump()` doing inside the `sql` statement  something fishy

Comment: I was not aware that using var_dump() is a silly way of getting the data from the form to the sql statement. But thanks to @MarkBaker for getting me on the right path to make this work.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know why are you trying to use `var_dump` to execute the `SQL` statement, that makes no sense, and then a `;` too that will terminate the `sql`, if you talk about the error

```
$sql ="UPDATE posts SET postCopy= var_dump ($_POST["postCopy"]); WHERE id=123456789";
```

change it to

```
$sql ="UPDATE posts SET postCopy= '".$_POST['postCopy']."' WHERE id=123456789";
```

and the error will go away.

*Note : This is not the optimal way and an open invite to `sql` injection, you should use `prepared statements` and `parameterized queries` either use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MYSQLI](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)*

Comment: I'll do some more research! Thanks for your help, I think this has me headed in the right direction- using the optimal solution.

Comment: you are welcome @AndrewBentley glad i was of some help.

Comment: you can mark the answer as selected if it works for you so that others might also get help who are facing the similar problem